# C++ vector, initialization from istream_iterator why do I have to use braced list initialization?

Tags: c++, syntax, stl

In this code.

```
vector<int> iVect{std::istream_iterator<int>(cin),std::istream_iterator()};
```

why do I have to use the uniform initialization syntax, instead of using the regular syntax?

Comment: First, you are missing `<int>` from the second iterator constructor, and secondly, why do you think you do? You should ask about and show us the code that *doesn't* work (rather than asking about code you haven't shown us), and make sure you include the full error message.

Comment: Isn't your second std::istream_iterator() missing a template argument?
What is the context of this code, where do you place it?

Comment: Because otherwise it declares a function. Search for "most vexing parse".

Comment: #include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
 vector<int> iVect(istream_iterator<int>(cin),istream_iterator<int>());
 copy(begin(iVect),end(iVect),ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
} this is my original code. The error I get is the following  tmp.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
tmp.cpp:9:18: error: no matching function for call to ‘begin(std::vector<int> (&)(std::istream_iterator<int>, std::istream_iterator<int> (*)()))’
  copy(begin(iVect),end(iVect),ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));

Comment: @Maths Please add your code to the question, not in the comments.